# Define colour and marker in matplotlib using two different columns

Tags: python, matplotlib, formatting, data-visualization, scatter

I am creating a scatter plot using matplotlib.

I am using two different columns in my dataframe to define two parameters of each they are site location and depth under ground that a sample was found.

I want to format the plots of the scatter so that the site location is a specific colour and then sample depth is a different marker type. At the moment I have just managed to separate out by colour:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Sites" : ["Site 1","Site 1", "Site 1", "Site 1", "Site 3", "Site 3"],
               "Depth" : ["a" , "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"],
               "D/L_FAA" : [0.1 , 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6],
               "D/L_THAA" : [0.1 , 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6]})
df
Out[8]: 
    Sites Depth  D/L_FAA  D/L_THAA
0  Site 1     a      0.1       0.1
1  Site 1     b      0.2       0.2
2  Site 1     c      0.3       0.3
3  Site 1     d      0.4       0.4
4  Site 3     e      0.5       0.5
5  Site 3     f      0.6       0.6

ax = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
groups = df.groupby(['Sites'])
for name, group in groups:
    plt.plot(group["D/L_FAA"], group["D/L_FAA"], marker='o', linestyle='', markersize=5, label=name)
```

[Just colours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXfuR.png)

This is what I want to achieve:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDkNk.png)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in a few lines by using `sns.scatterplot` from seaborn.

See code below:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({"Sites" : ["Site 1","Site 1", "Site 1", "Site 1", "Site 3", "Site 3"],
               "Depth" : ["a" , "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"],
               "D/L_FAA" : [0.1 , 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6],
               "D/L_THAA" : [0.1 , 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6]})
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='D/L_FAA',y='D/L_THAA',hue='Sites',style='Depth')
plt.show()
```

And the output gives:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to do this so that the markers and colours aren't separated on the legend?

Comment: I have updated the image of what I would like to achieve to make this a bit clearer

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68591271/how-can-i-combine-hue-and-style-groups-in-a-seaborn-legend) out