# Remove style entries from seaborn lineplot legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, legend

I have a pandas dataframe with name, date, strenght, protocol columns.

I am plotting a seaborn lineplot with

- date column as x;
- strenght column as y;
- protocol column as hue;
- name column as style.

I wanted that only the hue label appeared in the legend but as it is now I have a protocol legend followed by a name legend.

Do you have a solution that stays inside seaborn for that?

My code is, without any fancyness:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name':['A','A','B','B','C','C','D','D'],
    'date':[1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2],
    'strenght':[1,10,2,5,6,5,10,20],
    'protocol':['a','a','b','b','a','a','b','b']})
sns.lineplot(data = df,   x = 'date', y = 'strenght', hue = 'protocol', style = 'name')
```

protocol

- a
- b

name

- .. A
- -- B
- -* C
- *- D

And I would like to have just

protocol

- a
- b

with the two different colors showing

Comment: I am aware of this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68591271/how-can-i-combine-hue-and-style-groups-in-a-seaborn-legend
but I'd like to remain inside seaborn options for future purposes.

Comment: Seaborn is a high-level API for matplotlib. Saying _I'd like to remain inside seaborn options_ is explicitly inclusive for referencing the underlying matplotlib methods for customization, and correctly configuring the pandas dataframe.

Comment: thank you! Do you have any suggestion on where to move my focus or how I could configure my df?

Answer (score 0):

- As per the duplicate

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name':['A','A','B','B','C','C','D','D'],
    'date':[1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2],
    'strenght':[1,10,2,5,6,5,10,20],
    'protocol':['a','a','b','b','a','a','b','b']})
ax = sns.lineplot(data = df,   x = 'date', y = 'strenght', hue = 'protocol', style = 'name')

h, l = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(h[0:3], l[0:3], bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0., fontsize=13)
```

[image]